# Can install4j customize language seletion in welcome page?

Tags: install4j

I use install4j for multiple language installation,

We can select the language after jre initial, but I want to customize the language selection bundle with welcome page.

Anything possible?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the language on a regular screen since the language must be set before the screen/action system is initialized.

However, the installer has a "Replacement script for language code" property. You can use that to show your own language selection GUI or add your own logic for selecting the installer language.